# What is the frequency of color and depth information, and are they synchronized?

Tags: google-project-tango

I am creating an augmented reality application that uses the depth information to change how objects render within the color image. I'm not sure how frequently I should expect new frames or how to make sure I'm matching the correct depth samples with the right color image frames.

Answer (score 3):

The Tango Phone Development Kit and Tango Tablet Development Kit both update the RGB image at an average of 25hz. The depth for the Phone is sampled at 5hz, while the Tablet currently runs at 2-3hz, but may increase in later software releases.

The color and depth data are not synchronized, but in both platforms the API provides timestamps for all data as well as an interface to request data at a given timestamp, so the application can decide how best to manage the data.